# Issues after converting a Tradingview strategy to v4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

So I updated this v2 strategy to v4 and it is loading successfully; also, TV isn't giving any errors. However, suddenly the % profitable trades went down from 75% to 50%.

My question is, was the script repainting and is now showing the actual results; or have I messed something up while making the conversion?

I would welcome any help,
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The default behavior of the security() function was changed.](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed) To achieve parity with the v2 version, you need to add `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` to each separate `security()` call in your script.

Note that lookahead allows you to 'cheat' by checking historical values from higher timeframes before they are reasonably available (e.g. getting 1D high/low/close before the day has actually closed on the main intraday chart), so for the purpose of correct backtesting, you should probably leave it turned off.